# How do I make Canon imageCLASS D420 work in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, canon

How can I install a driver for the printer **Canon imageCLASS D420**? The default drivers shipped with Ubuntu do not work with it.

I tried to install Canon's drivers, but I got the message:

> There was an error during the CUPS operation client error format not supported.

Canon support told me that their drivers can't support Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the answers you're looking for here...
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1427330&p=11871878&highlight=#post11871878
and here
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1723101&page=4&p=11680367#post11680367

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.